# What Do Computer Scientists Do?

Tags: education

I want to know '***What Computer Scientists Actually Do***'. It is kind of a very vague thing to me. I don't know anything about it, actually.
I have many people in my family who chose and plan on choosing CS but I do not understand what they do after being done with their Academic Classes and perhaps after their placement too.
Do they continue with their job and work on their own projects too ? If so, then what kind of projects do they work on ?
And what if one doesn't go for business administration ? What designations do they get in companies ?

These may look like different questions but it is actually just one question and those may be parts of it. All of these make up that question. 
What they study and how they apply their knowledge or do they even (I mean how many of them).

You can understand this I think. That first line is everything here.

Thank You !

Comment: This question is not about computer science or even education but about census data. I recommend you look up up said data for your country; they know which jobs people with any given education have.

Comment: Community votes, please: is this offtopic?

Comment: As far as I know, most computer science majors are programmers. A few open start-ups, or work in software design or algorithm design. A handful are academics. Some probably leave computer science for a different career.

Comment: Thank You for your response Yuval Sir. I was also thinking the same, or along the same line if not the same. But since they have Mathematical influences in their programming (I think), I think they work more on projects that require heavy Maths and Science.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Can you back that up with data?

Comment: No, it's just an educated guess. It also really seems that people go to study computer science because they want to be programmers.

Comment: Data from England (http://www.hefce.ac.uk/analysis/supplydemand/destination/) supports my claims, if you interpret "IT professional" as an inclusive form of programmer (they also have "IT technician" which is much less common). That's especially true for the top universities.

Comment: And also, Raphael, looking up the 'data' of my Country is pointless because job opportunities etc. are not just set to being limited to the country I am in. And in fact, 'data' on these is actually very stupid thing to bring up. People who 'are' computer scientists (so to say) and those who have opted for it and have gone through 2nd year or even the first one are the ones who can explain what really happens there etc. etc. But of course, anyone can contribute according to their knowledge, which is good, actually.

Comment: And I also want to know if most of these people stick with their initial placement for a long time period or not. You may know some people so maybe you can tell me from their movement. Most people in my family who are through CS etc. don't really do so, but that is only the case when one gets a nice place to work with a high salary, I think

Comment: Please don't use the comments for general discussion or back-and-forth.  If you want to clarify what you are looking for or justify the motivation for your question, please edit the question -- don't leave comments in the comment thread.  This is not a discussion forum.  Comments exist only to help you improve your question, not for general discussion or chat.

Comment: @Raj 1) You want to replace your own research by asking here, and openly reject the prospect of objective answers. That makes this question unsuitable for this platform.  2) We (moderators and community-moderating users) are paying for this site with considerable time investments. Rude behaviour will not be tolerated.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus There's a big spectrum of things under "IT professional" -- programmers, engineers, architects, consultants, ...

Comment: Since you think that “ 'data' on these is actually very stupid thing to bring up”, I don't see what kind of answers you could expect. And please [be nice](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).